# Show message every x percent iterations Ruby

Tags: ruby

I want my code to show a message every 20% of items processed.
I am not very happy with the way I am doing. I am sure have a smarter way

The way I am doing:

```
count = 0
size = foo.get_items_size (items)
target = 20
loop all items
   items_processed = count*100 / size
   if items_processed == target
      puts "#{items_processed}% items"
      target += 20
   end
   count +=1
end
```

Comment: Note that due to `items_processed == target` your code only works reliably if the number of items is a multiple of 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could incorporate the counter into your loop via [`with_index`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_index) and make your code a little more robust by comparing the current percentage to your target via `>=` rather than `==`:

```
items = ('A'..'M').to_a
target = 20

items.each.with_index(1) do |item, index|
  puts item # process item

  if index.quo(items.size) >= target.quo(100)
    puts "#{target}% processed"
    target += 20
  end
end
```

This will print 20%, 40%, 60% etc. whenever exceeding that percentage:

```
A
B
C
20% processed
D
E
F
40% processed
G
H
60% processed
I
J
K
80% processed
L
M
100% processed
```

Note that the actual percentages are 23%, 46%, 62%, and 85%.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [`Enumerable#each.with_index`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_index) in combination with of only printing the output when the current `index` is a multiple of 20:

```
process_steps = (1..5).map { items.size / _1 }

items.each.with_index(1) do |item, index|
  # do stuff with item

  puts "#{index}% items processes" if process_steps.include?(index)
end
```

Comment: That's prints every 20 items, not every 20%

Comment: You are right, I updated my answer to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the below code is helpful:

```
items = 1..100
target_percent = 20
step = ((target_percent/100.0) * items.size).round

items.each.with_index(1) do |item, index|
  # Some other working logic
  puts "#{index}% of work done!" if index.modulo(step).zero?
end
```

Since I don't know what's in the item list, I have just considered it as an array.
This will also work if you wish to change the `target_percent`.

Comment: Try to run it for `items = 1..99`

Comment: Yes, didn't consider that :) We can round off the step to avoid mod with float.

Comment: Also note that `#{index}%` prints the item's index, not the percentage.

Comment: I had actually figured that out, but I thought it was just the print statement so didn't update it.
But, if we try to get the percentage back from the index value, we would, in some cases, not get the expected value (it would be approximate).
We can print it like this `((index/size.to_f) * 100).round` if we want. Right?

Comment: One last nitpick: if you run your code for `items = 1..13` it would print _"69% of work done"_ when processing `9`, although `8` was already at 62%.

Answer (score 0):

[each_slice](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice) might be what you are looking for:

```
items = (1..30)

slice_size = items.size/(100/20)
processed = 0
items.each_slice(slice_size) do |slice|
  processed += slice.size
  slice.each do |item|
    puts item #process item
  end
  puts "#{processed} from #{items.size} items processed"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it with slices and indexes:

```
items=(1..23).to_a
step=20.0/100
steps=(items.length*step).round
items.each_slice(steps).with_index{|slice, ind|
    puts "Accurate: #{((steps*ind)/items.length.to_f*100).round}% processed, now processing: #{slice[0..2]}..#{slice[-3..-1]}" 
    puts "Dumb down: #{(ind/(1.0/step)*100).round}% processed"
    puts 
}   
#puts "Done!"
```

Every 20% report implies process 5 slices with assumably the last slice being the remainder if the length of items is not evenly divisible by 5.

You can report progress either accurately (22%, 43%, 65%, 87% in for 5 buckets totaling 23 items) or dumb that down to 20%,40%,60%,80%. I have shown both here.

Example prints:

```
Accurate: 0% processed, now processing: [1, 2, 3]..[3, 4, 5]
Dumb down: 0% processed

Accurate: 22% processed, now processing: [6, 7, 8]..[8, 9, 10]
Dumb down: 20% processed

Accurate: 43% processed, now processing: [11, 12, 13]..[13, 14, 15]
Dumb down: 40% processed

Accurate: 65% processed, now processing: [16, 17, 18]..[18, 19, 20]
Dumb down: 60% processed

Accurate: 87% processed, now processing: [21, 22, 23]..[21, 22, 23]
Dumb down: 80% processed
```

You can also do standing progress percentages:

```
items.each_slice(steps).with_index{|slice, ind|
    printf("\r %s", "#{ind/(1.0/step)*100}%")
    sleep(0.6)
}   
puts "\rDone!     "
```

Or progress bars:

```
items.each_slice(steps).with_index{|slice, ind|
    printf("\rProgress: [%-20s]", "|"*(ind*5))
    sleep(0.6)
}   
puts "\rDone!                                  "
```

Comment: When processing in fixed slices you can have rounding errors that add up. For example, with your initial data `items=(1..23).to_a`, the slices are 1-5, 6-10, 11-15, 16-20, and 21-23. However, item 14 is already at 61% and 19 is at 83%.

Comment: Well yes -- hence why I did both 'accurate' and 'dumb' versions. There will always be errors unless the processing to be done is a perfect multiple of the reporting interval, no?

Comment: My point is that you slice those too late: 13=57%, 14=61%, 15=65%. You should slice after 14 (i.e. "Accurate: 61%"), not after 15 (same for 19/20). If you want to stay as close to 20% intervals as possible, your slices don't have a fixed size.

Comment: I agree with you math. But suppose if 20% of 23 elements is 4.6 elements on average, the only 'fix' is to do the reporting item by item (as you did) or accept that each block is just an approximation. Even if you report by item so it is as close as possible to 20%, you usually cannot report in the middle of one item so you will naturally be a little off no matter how you calculate unless the total of items is evenly divisible into the reporting interval, no?

Comment: Alternatively, you could calculate the slice sizes in advance by carrying over the rounding error, like those raster [line drawing algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_drawing_algorithm): 1st slice is 4.6 rounded up to **5** (diff 0.4). The 2nd slice is 4.6-0.4=4.2, rounded up to **5** (diff 0.8), the 3rd slice is 4.6-0.8=3.8, rounded up to **4** (diff 0.2). 4th is 4.6-0.2=4.4, rounded up to **5** (diff 0.6). The 5th slice is 4.6-0.6= **4** (no diff).

Comment: I guess this is why your OS reports the file will take 2 hours to copy, then 5 minutes then it is done in 3 minutes from the start ;-)